# Unix-Expect:Capture the output of a command as a expect variable

Tags: shell, variables, unix, tcl, expect

I am trying to capture the output of a program in unix, and use it as a variable in the expect script. When I excecute the program, I will get something like this:

```
[user@svr]# ./passwdgenerator
1234*&^^[user@svr]#
```

As you can see, the "1234*&^^" is the password I want to capture and put it into the expect script:

```
set user user1
set password [open ./passwdgenerator]
spawn ssh $user@server1.com
expect "password:"
send "$password\r"
```

Obviously it's not working currently, just wonder how I should write this. Have tried this on the txt file before, worked. but when it is a program output, and for security reason we don't want to store password in the text file, so it doesn't work. Any expert could give me a hand? Greatly greatly appreciated.!

Comment: Try `send "$password"` or (maybe) `send "$password\n"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line

```
set password [open ./passwdgenerator]
```

change to

```
set password [exec ./passwdgenerator]
```